# Как отключить декоратор границ QDockWidget в ОС Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

При использовании QDockWidget в ОС Linux, таких, как Manjaro KDE, Fedora Gnome, с версией Qt5.15, не применяется пользовательская таблица стилей qss для границы закрепленых QDockWidget, а так же для границы QFrame, помещенных в QDockWidget. Вместо этого отображается системный декоратор для границы QDockWidget, который не удаётся отключить с помощью таблицы стилей. Существует ли способ отключить системный декоратор?

[image: Пример]

А так выглядит правильное оформление (в ОС Windows 8)

[image: Пример]

Вот упрощенный вариант таблицы стилей, которую я применяю:

```
QMainWindow {
    background: #2C2C34;
}
QMainWindow::separator {
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    background: #2C2C34;
}

QFrame {
    border-left: 1px solid #32363F;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #32363F;
    border-right: 1px solid #32363F;
    border-top: none;
    background-color: #292930;
}

QDockWidget {
    border: none;
    font-size: 8pt;
    color: #A0A5AA;
}
QDockWidget::title {
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    text-align: center left;
    border-left: 1px solid #32363F;
    border-top: 1px solid #32363F;
    border-right: 1px solid #32363F;
    background: #25272C;
}
QDockWidget::close-button,
QDockWidget::float-button {
    icon-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    border: none;
    background: #25272C;
}
QDockWidget::close-button:hover,
QDockWidget::float-button:hover {
    background: rgb(52, 59, 72);
}
QDockWidget::close-button:pressed,
QDockWidget::float-button:pressed {
    background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255);
}
QDockWidget::close-button {
    min-width: 20px;
    min-height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 1px; bottom: 0px; right: 1px;
    subcontrol-position: center right;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
    position: absolute;

}
QDockWidget::float-button {
    min-width: 20px;
    min-height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 1px; bottom: 0px; right: 24px;
    subcontrol-position: center right;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
    position: absolute;

}
```

В упрощенном варианте получается вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А ожидалось получить такой результат (здесь изображение без верхней рамки, т.к. я его скопировал из QT Designer):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройки background для QDockWidget

[image: Настройки background для QDockWidget]

Вариант с отступами 0px (заметно смещение QDockWidget::title и вторая темная граница с закругленными углами вокруг док виджетов)

[image: Вариант с отступами 0px]

Вариант с отступами 2px (появились белые границы)

[image: Вариант с отступами 0px]

Comment: проведите код. как по картинкам то гадать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

```
app.setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Fusion"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Из приведённого кода на KDE Plasma получилось сделать такое:

[image: здесь могла быть ваша реклама]

```
QDockWidget {
   ...
   background-color: #292930;
}
```

И компоновщикам у доков, в которых фрейм, выставил параметры `layout[Left|Top|Right|Bottom]Margin` и `layoutSpacing` в `2`.

Для Федоры - можно отключить границу, выставив альфа-канал в 0 (четвёртый параметр):

```
QDockWidget {
   ...
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Открываем UI в дизайн режиме, справа в дереве графически объектов выбираем компоновщик (layout), который был применён к доку, и ниже в параметрах ищем эти свойства. Можете попробовать выставить в 0, а не 2.

Comment: @Helg1980 Добавьте скрин с федоры приведённого кода.

Comment: @Helg1980 а если фрейму `margin: -2px` допустим поставить?

Comment: @Helg1980 еще идею подкинул в ответе

Comment: Да, это действительно сработало, граница исчезла. Спасибо! 

Единственное отступ не понятно как уменьшить между виджетами, у меня 1px выставлен для разделителя, а там образовался отступ в 5 px;

Answer (score 0):

Под рукой нет KDE/Gnome для проверки, но судя по документации не хватает резета бордера у самого док виджета.

```
...
QFrame {
    border-left: 1px solid #32363F;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #32363F;
    border-right: 1px solid #32363F;
    border-top: none;
    background-color: #292930;
}

QDockWidget {
    border: none; /** <--- reset border style **/
    font-size: 8pt;
    color: #A0A5AA;
}

QDockWidget::title {
...
```